# Correct way to start InboundChannelAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using annotation based

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel channel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}


@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "channel",poller = @Poller(fixedDelay="1000"))
public MessageSource<?> inbound() {}
```

works perfectly.

But now I dont want it to start  automatically , what is the correct way to start/stop?
p.s.
I am not using IntegrationFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `@InboundChannelAdapter` attributes:

```
/**
 * {@code SmartLifecycle} options.
 * Can be specified as 'property placeholder', e.g. {@code ${foo.autoStartup}}.
 * @return if the channel adapter is started automatically or not.
 */
String autoStartup() default "true";
```

So, with the `false` it is not going to start automatically.
You would need to autowire the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` bean somewhere in your services to `start()` it manually.

See `@EndpointId` annotation to place alongside with that `@InboundChannelAdapter`.

Or you can use a Control Bus pattern to perform `start()` command:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#control-bus

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations

There won't be too much difference with Java DSL, unless you wouldn't need to search for `@EndpointId` since there is just obvious `id()` on the `EdnpointSpec` exposed along side with the `poller()`.

Comment: wow,So simple with SourcePollingChannelAdapter, can i find documentation about it? and what is the use of  EndpointId? as i used it without one

Comment: The `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` is a bean created from that `@InboundChannelAdapter` and around that your `inbound()` method. By See docs I shared about `@EndpointId` and its JavaDoc is good, too.

Comment: any issues binding  same from test? Error creating bean with name 'sourcePollingChannelAdapter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source must not be null

Comment: The `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` is not supposed to be used in the end-user code, even test. Therefore it would be great to know more about your use-case. Please, raise a new SO thread with much more info what you are trying to achieve in your test.

Comment: so you are saying that i should not use SourcePollingChannelAdapter explicitly at all ?

Comment: You can autowire created by the framework, but it is not so easy to create it manually yourself and you have already faced that problem with null source.

Comment: yes too much effort

Comment: That's why I asked you about a new SO question. So, we would revise your use-case in details and would find some high-level solution for you. In general the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` component testing is a Framework responsibility. You, in your project, should test your components and your business logic.

Comment: exactly, i am doing component test: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70811092/