# Component testing of spring integration framework using SourcePollingChannelAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to write a small component test for springboot with spring integration framework process using some h2 database and embedded kafka.

I am not using IntegrationFlow/dsl.

So everything configured by annotations.

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel channel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}


@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "channel",autoStartup = "false", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay="1000"))
public MessageSource<?> inbound() {}
```

In the `SpringBootTest` , I want to insert couple of rows to H2 database, and trigger the process, probably with: `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`, and assert the output.

Currently having issues with autowiring `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`
or bean not found exception or source is null.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MainConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringIntegrationTest
@SpringBootTest(properties = ...)
@Sql(scripts={"classpath:schema.sql"})
class Test {
   @Autowired
   @Lazy
   SourcePollingChannelAdapter inboundAdapter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that `autoStartup = "false"` if database is empty by default. So, even if that `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`  is going to call SELECT on your DB it won't emit any messages until you INSERT that testing data.

It is not clear what is your flow afterwards. But you can take a look into Spring Integration Testing framework how to replace some endpoint in your flow for testing purpose, like assertion: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#test-context

To determine the reason of your autowiring problem, we need to see more of your test configuration code: you probably just don't include that integration configuration into your testing scope somehow. If `@Bean` is there and its configuration is visible, then you can autowire it.

Comment: not sure what you mean by not including integration configuration but i updated the post

Comment: I see there is only `MainConfiguration` included. Is that exactly a class where you define that `@InboundChannelAdapter`?

Comment: The `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` is redundant: the `@SpringBootTest` brings that for us. The `@EnableConfigurationProperties` must not be there on a test class.

Comment: ok, but SourcePollingChannelAdapter still not wired on request.

Comment: So, do you include the `@Configuration` class with that `@InboundChannelAdapter` into your test scope? Is there something like `@SpringBootApplication` visible for the test to initiate a Spring Integration infrastructure? I mean as long as there is no `@EnableIntegration` visible for test configuration, the Spring Integration is out of use.

Comment: yes,   `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MainConfiguration.class})`,  `@InboundChannelAdapter` is defined there. the error is  `No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter`

Comment: Ok. And where is auto-configuration trigger?

Comment: omg!!! @EnableAutoConfiguration was missing. all works now of course.